# How to serialize custom boolean fields from model 'AbstractUser' in django rest framework serializers.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am unable to serialize custom model booleanfields is_subuser, is_student in django rest framework, even if i try to post using postman still i am unable, but i am able to see this two fields in django admin backend.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
        is_school = models.BooleanField('school status',default=False)
        is_student = models.BooleanField('student status',default=False)
        is_subuser = models.BooleanField('subuser status',default=False)
```

serializers.py

```
    
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? Because this should work.

Comment: I did not define routers properly, it has been solved